# Limit template to only one page in adminhtml

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

For now I have directly edited this file

> \vendor\magento\module-backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\grid\extended.phtml

and I have added a button as you can see from the photo below

[image]

But this template file edits all the pages in `Reports>Sales` and I would like to have this button being visible only for `Reports>Sales>>Orders`

How could I limit the button only for `Orders`?